# Liferay service builder: is there a practical limit for max number of entities in a webapp?

Tags: java, liferay

I wonder if there is a practical limit on the number of entities you can really use in a single webapp? Are there any empirical guidelines to recommend? (Fictitious example: "Do not use more than 30 entities if your main memory on the server is below 1 GB").

Some background: I observed that the number of cross-references in the generated java files grow quadratically, because in one of the directories
(in the src/.../base), each java file/mapped entity imports every other entity.

I have 58 entities currently. 
To illustrate, the file service/ClpSerializer.java (which is always generated) has 17000 lines. My war file containing only generated code (and no business logic yet) has 8MB compressed, and 43 MB uncompressed. Yes, my tables are big and have many columns.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting all in one service.xml , why dont you use Module Specific ??

Comment: One service.xml for each table? One service.xml for every 10 tables, say?